# How to do a "show (e.g Push)" segue programatically without animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard, segue

How can I do a "show (e.g Push)" segue programatically without animation? 
None of the solutions I've found works the same way as the one in storyboard.

Comment: what should happen? the new view should just appear instantly over the previous one?

Comment: Yes, but not presented modally, it has to be the same way as the "show (e.g Push)" segue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What the `show (e.g. Push)` segue does internally is to call
 [-[UIViewController showViewController:sender:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/showViewController:sender:)

Calling this method on your view controller itself, will trigger the appropriate way of presenting the view controller you are passing.

```
// Swift
self.showViewController(viewControllerToShow, sender: self)
// Objective-C
[self showViewController: viewControllerToShow sender: self];
```

The animation can be removed, by wrapping the call in an [+[UIView performWithoutAnimation:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/performWithoutAnimation:) block.

```
// Swift
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.showViewController(viewControllerToShow, sender: self)
}
// Objective-C
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^void () {
    [self showViewController: viewControllerToShow sender: self];
}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Truly appriciate it.